# Datatables Requested Unknown Parameter '4' for row 0 column 4

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables

Whenever I add a new column it will also change the "Unknown Parameter 'x'' to the number of my columns. When I click okay, it will display the table, though. What could be the cause of this? A help is highly appreciated.

Response:

```
{"aaData":[
    {"ordinancenumber":"1",
     "title":"A",
     "dateimplemented":"1996-09-26",
     "actions":"*insert html button codes here*"}]}
```

HTML:

```
<table  width="100%" id="tblordinancelist" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Ordinance #</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Date Implemented</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
var table = $('#tblordinancelist').DataTable( {
      stateSave: true,
      "bLengthChange":false,
      "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url('Legislative/loadOrdinance'); ?>",
      "language": {
          "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_",
          "zeroRecords": "No matching ordinance found.",
          "emptyTable":  "No ordinance.",
          "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
          "infoFiltered": "(Filtered from _MAX_ total ordinances)",
          "loadingRecords": "Loading ordinances...",
          "infoEmpty":      ""
      },
      "columns": [
          {
            "mData": "ordinancenumber",
              "autoWidth": false,
              "width": "150px" },
          {
            "mData": "title",
              "autoWidth": false,
              "width": "100px" },
          {
            "mData": "dateimplemented",
              "autoWidth": false,
              "width": "200px"  },
          { 
            "mData": "actions",
              "autoWidth": false,
              "width": "200px"  }
      ]
  });
```

Comment: `"mData": "dateimplemented",` is used twice in `DataTable( {});` configuration. Remove or change name. since your response has only three fields, remove it.  `Actions` is not right defined and not present in the response.

Comment: Okay, I have changed it and updated the code above. But I suppose it doesn't matter if it will use the same data for another column. Still getting the same error.

Comment: From where do you have that jquery plugin because here: https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html   a definiton looks like this `{ "data": "name" },` not like `{ "mData": "name" },`. Tip: check via F12 developer console in the browser what is happening.

Comment: A couple of things to try: Add `'bServerSide': true,` to the initialisation code.  Change `$('#tblordinancelist').DataTable(` to `$('#tblordinancelist').dataTable(`. The syntax you've used is v1.9, but initialising with uppercase `DataTable` is v1.10.  I think it is backwards compatible but it's worth a try.